# Jax-WS and Spring-security Conflict

Tags: java, spring, spring-security, jax-ws, web.xml

I have defined a Jax-WS webservice in my Spring web mvc project. All the web service methods worked fine as expected when I tested the wsdl operations using SOAP-UI.

I have included spring-security filter for authentication and authorization. Now, I could access the wsdl but could not perform any operation on it. 
I am getting the following error message in SOAP UI:

**HTTP Status 405 - Request method &#39;POST&#39; not supported**

Following is the spring-security filter that I have added in web.xml:

```
<filter>  
    <filter-name>springSecurityFilterChain</filter-name>  
    <filter-class>org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy</filter-class>  
</filter>    
<filter-mapping>  
    <filter-name>springSecurityFilterChain</filter-name>  
    <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>  
</filter-mapping>
```

And,my wsdl is there at: http://localhost:8080/MyProject/MyService?wsdl

Please let me know how to overcome this issue.

Comment: are you handling the POST method in your controller? Have you got defined any <security-constraint>s in your web.xml?

Comment: @ingenious, thank you very much for the information. No, I am not handling it in my controller. I have created a java class and exposed it as a jax-ws webservice. As per your suggestion, I have added a          <securtiy-constraint> to MyService in web.xml by ommitting all the constraints. But still, the issue is there.

Comment: To include security-constraint, I have followed this post: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15024235/how-to-exclude-one-url-from-authorization

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Got it!! Included the following element in spring-security.xml:

```
<http pattern="/MyService**" security="none"/>
```