# How to exclude one url from authorization when using Spring MVC

Tags: java, spring-mvc, jakarta-ee, tomcat6

I am using Spring MVC 4.1.6 to write a web app running on Tomcat 6.0.43 using java 6.45.  I am using form based authentication, and I want all pages to be secure except for the login page and the resources folder, which contains images, etc.  I have already read the answer to [How to exclude one url from authorization](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15024235/how-to-exclude-one-url-from-authorization) but it does not work for me.  I get an error message in my browser "HTTP Status 403 - Access to the requested resource has been denied."  I have spent hours trying to figure this out without any success.  If anyone has any ideas, they would be greatly appreciated.  Shown below is the relevant part of the web.xml.

```
  <!-- specify which resources are restricted for users -->
  <security-constraint>
     <web-resource-collection>
        <web-resource-name>User</web-resource-name>
        <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
     </web-resource-collection>
     <auth-constraint><role-name>user</role-name></auth-constraint>
  </security-constraint>

  <!-- specify which resources are not restricted -->
  <security-constraint>
     <web-resource-collection>
        <web-resource-name>Login</web-resource-name>
        <url-pattern>/login</url-pattern>
        <url-pattern>/resources/*</url-pattern>
     </web-resource-collection>
     <!-- no auth-constraint -->
  </security-constraint>


  <!-- specify all the roles defined for this web app -->
  <security-role><role-name>admin</role-name></security-role>
  <security-role><role-name>user</role-name> </security-role>


  <!-- specify how the user will be authenticatated -->
  <form-login-config>
     <auth-method>FORM</auth-method>
     <form-login-page>/login</form-login-page>
     <form-error-page>/login</form-error-page>
  </form-login-config>
```

And finally, here is the folder structure of my web app as it is deployed in the tomcat server.

[image]

Comment: I'm not familiar with that style of security configuration, but try putting your "no auth-constraint" stanza first; security rules are often applied based on the first match found.

Answer (score 0):

It turns out there was an error in the web.xml that the tomcat server was not complaining about.  Once I fixed the error, then the http 403 error went away.
Here is the correct web.xml .

```
      <!-- specify which resources are restricted for users -->
  <security-constraint>
     <web-resource-collection>
        <web-resource-name>protected resources</web-resource-name>
        <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
     </web-resource-collection>
     <auth-constraint><role-name>user</role-name></auth-constraint>
  </security-constraint>

  <!-- specify which resources are not restricted -->
  <security-constraint>
     <web-resource-collection>
        <web-resource-name>unrestricted resources</web-resource-name>
        <url-pattern>/login</url-pattern>
        <url-pattern>/resources/*</url-pattern>
     </web-resource-collection>
     <!-- no auth-constraint -->
  </security-constraint>


  <!-- specify all the roles defined for this web app -->
  <security-role><role-name>admin</role-name></security-role>
  <security-role><role-name>user</role-name> </security-role>


  <!-- specify how the user will be authenticatated -->
  <login-config>
     <auth-method>FORM</auth-method>
     <realm-name>default</realm-name>
     <form-login-config>
        <form-login-page>/login</form-login-page>
        <form-error-page>/login</form-error-page>
     </form-login-config>
  </login-config>
```