# Correct path to static resources in order to omit them from authorization-constraint

Tags: java, authentication, websphere, web.xml

I have a java ee-struts application using websphere and everything is restricted if the user is not logged in. Even the static resources like css and images.I would like to unrestrict access for 2 things, the `style.css` and `blue_logo.gif` files so that they are available without beeing registered. I have found this post [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15062058/14923242) that shows how to do it but i don't know how to write the exact path to specify each of the 2 resources that i need.Could someone please provide me with the exact path based on the folder structure that i provided? Thank you

This is the code that i have and that restricts everything.This is from the web.xml file located in the WEB-INF folder of my module.

```
<security-constraint>
   <display-name>ABC_Access<display-name>
   <web-resource-collection>
       <web-resource-name>All_resources</web-resource-name>
       <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
   <web-resource-collection>
   <auth-constraint>
       <description>all_authent</description>
       <role-name>all</role-name>
   </auth-constraint>
</security-constraint>
```

my Folder Structure is :

```
src>main>webapp>WEB-INF>web.xml
               >css>style.css
               >images>blue_logo.gif
```

Answer (score 0):

You should have **additional** constraint like this, WITHOUT `auth-constraint`. Check this - "If there is no authorization constraint, the container must accept the request without requiring user authentication." [Specifying an Authorization Constraint](https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/tutorial/security-webtier002.htm#GJJCG)

```
<security-constraint>
   <display-name>Unprotected resources<display-name>
   <web-resource-collection>
       <web-resource-name>unprotected_resources</web-resource-name>
       <url-pattern>/images/*</url-pattern>
       <url-pattern>/css/*</url-pattern>
   <web-resource-collection>
    <!-- do not provide auth-constraint -->
</security-constraint>
```